# Clarification about Scala Future that never complete and its effect on other callbacks

Tags: scala, callback, future

While re-reading scala.lan.org's page detailing Future [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html), I have stumbled up on the following sentence:

> In the event that some of the callbacks never complete (e.g. the callback contains an infinite loop), the other callbacks may not be executed at all. In these cases, a potentially blocking callback must use the blocking construct (see below).

Why may the other callbacks *not* be executed at all? I may install a number of callbacks for a given Future. The thread that completes the Future, may or may not execute the callbacks. But, because one callback is not playing footsie, the rest should not be penalized, I think.

One possibility I can think of is the way ExecutionContext is configured. If it is configured with one thread, then this *may* happen, but that is a specific behaviour and a not generally expected behaviour.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: "but that is a specific behaviour and a not generally expected behaviour": or in other words, this *may* happen (that the callback is never executed). Which seems entirely in line with what your quoted text says.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Agree with your explanation. In fact, yours underlines my inference that if I am not careful about managing a possibly never-ending computation in a callback, I may be in for a surprise with regards to other callbacks. My point is that the article on Future could have exemplified such **a possible fallout**; it sounds somewhat vague otherwise. What do you think? I am just curious about others' opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callbacks are called within an `ExecutionContext` that has an eventually limited number of threads - if not by the specific context implementation, then by the underlying operating system and/or hardware itself.

Let's say your system's limit is `OS_LIMIT` threads. You create `OS_LIMIT + 1` callbacks. From those, `OS_LIMIT` callbacks immediately get a thread each - and none ever terminate.

**How can you guarantee that the remaining 1 callback *ever* gets a thread?**

Sure, there could be some detection mechanisms built into the Scala library, but it's not possible in the general case to make an optimal implementation: maybe you *want* the callback to run for a month.

Instead (and this seems to be the approach in the Scala library), you could provide facilities for handling situations that *you*, the developer, know are risky. This removes the element of surprise from the system.

Perhaps most importantly - **it enables the developer to "bake in" the necessary information about handler/task characteristics directly *into* his/her program**, rather than relying on some obscure piece of language functionality (which may change from version to version).

Comment: Note that, even if there's an ability of "giving up" threads, the situation will eventually, with scaling, reduce into the same scenario.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwitftTomato :'it enables the developer..' - could you please elaborate a bit further? I am surely missing the hint but what do I 'bake in' and how? If I structure the callbacks in such a way that their number is always 2 (1 for the main thread) less than OS_THREADS, will you consider that to be one of the reasonable approaches? But then, a running application may have many such callbacks defined, and which is called when is unknown.

Comment: @Nirmalya : "what" is information such as "this callback may be indefinitely blocked by the preceding code", "how" - through the use of the provided API, such as `Await.result`. I'm not sure if I understand the rest of your question. Regardless, I'd like to point out that we are discussing the point of view of the *standard library* developer, who has to account for *any and all* applications.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwitftTomato: (View of Standard Library Developer) Point taken! I still think that the article on Future (scala.lang.org) should have elaborated this point.

Comment: @Nirmalya : glad I've provided an explanation that worked for you. Regarding the elaboration - it may indeed be a good idea. And, actually, there's nothing stopping you from [leaving feedback](http://docs.scala-lang.org/) (right-hand side) :).